# Offline Ros Bridge Intallation / without internet

Tags: powershell, installation, cmd, server, ros

We want to install Ros Bridge to our server. But we don't have internet access on server. Is it possible we can install without internet?

Thank you...

Comment: Clone the source code and drop it on with a USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the package and all it's dependencies on a different device (with similar architecture) like

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<rosdistro>-rosbridge-server --download-only
```

This will place the packages at */var/cache/apt/archives*. The files then can be used for installation without the need of downloading them again. So after moving them to your server, this can be done with

```
apt-get install ros-<rosdistro>-rosbridge-server
```